# How do I prove: $xyz(x-2)(y-2)(z-2)\leq\left(1+\frac{2(xy+yz+xz)}{3}\right)^3,\ x,y,z>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have a question which askes to prove:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} xyz(x-2)(y-2)(z-2)\leq\left(1+\frac{2(xy+yz+xz)}{3}\right)^3,\ x,y,z>0$?

My approach: I tried AM-GM inequality, didn't work well. So I tried substituting $2(xy+yz+xz)=(x+y+z)^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$, I couldn't proceed further. I even tried expanding the LHS, it's tedious. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: use $a = x+y+z, b = xy+yz+zx, c=xyz$.

Comment: @WangYeFei Maybe the author doesn't know about uvw's method ?

Answer (score 1):

We want $x+y+z$ largest when $xyz,xy+yz+zx$ fixed. By 3.83 in the Mathematical Inequalities (Volume 1) by Vasile Cîrtoaje, we can assume $x=y\le z$. Now we rewrite the inequality as $x=y$:

$$ x^2z(x-2)^2(z-2)\leq\left(1+\frac{2(x^2+2xz)}{3}\right)^3$$

We must have $z\ge 2$ otherwise left is smaller than zero, and right is larger than zero.

Now expand everything, we have

$$RHS-LHS=\frac{64x^3z^3+(69x^4+108x^3+36x^2)z^2+(48x^5+54x^4-72x^3+216x^2+108x)z+8x^6+36x^4+54x^2+27}{27}$$

Since $z\ge 2$ so $64x^3z^3\ge72x^3z$. All others are positive, so this is proved.

Remark: I suspect

$$xyz(x-2)(y-2)(z-2)\leq\left(1+\frac{(xy+yz+xz)}{3}\right)^3$$

Comment: We can show that $ 48x^5 + 54x^4 - 72x^3 + 216x^2 + 108x \geq 0 $ in the domain $ 0 \leq x$. (EG AMGM on $54x^4 -72x^3 + 24x \geq 0$.) $\quad$ Likewise, the remark at the end can be dealt with similarly.

Comment: @CalvinLin the remark at the end I think it is hard to deal with by direct expansion with all cases... It is easy if we consider the case with assumption $0\le x=y\le 1$ and $z\ge 2$. (Other cases are easy)